# sony android device remote screen capture

Tags: android, sony, screen-capture, remote-control

I have been looking through Sony's developer site.  Unlike other vendors I cannot see how you join their developer program.  I need to gain access to their APIs so that my app can be signed and warranted the special access permissions to allow me to remotely capture an Android display.

Comment: Registering as a "developer" will not get your signing keys to the platform - vendors only ever sign specific, carefully hand selected partner applications.  And typically, they would sign the app for you, rather than give you the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to use the screen capture ability available in the new Android 5.0 Lollipop release. This should let you take screen shots regardless of manufacturer.

http://developer.android.com/samples/ScreenCapture/index.html